# How to unlist a list of data frames into a single data frame in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list of data frames:

```
 lst<-list(data.frame(x=1:3,y=2:4, row.names=letters[1:3]),
           data.frame(z=1:4,w=2:5, row.names=letters[3:6]),
           data.frame(r=2:4,s=3:5, row.names=letters[2:4]))
 lst
[[1]]
  x y
a 1 2
b 2 3
c 3 4

[[2]]
  z w
c 1 2
d 2 3
e 3 4
f 4 5

[[3]]
  r s
b 2 3
c 3 4
d 4 5
```

My question is how to unlist it to a single data frame merged by rownames and replace NAs to 0 such as:

```
  x y z w r s
a 1 2 0 0 0 0
b 2 3 0 0 2 3
c 3 4 1 2 3 4
d 0 0 2 3 4 5
e 0 0 3 4 0 0
f 0 0 4 5 0 0
```

Comment: unnest is the keyword you're looking for

Comment: it doesn't support list

Comment: can you be sure that no combination of rowname and column name appears twice in the list of dataframes?

Comment: column names are unique but not rownames

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R:

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst,function(x) cbind(rowname=rownames(x),x))
df1 <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,all=T),lst2)
rownames(df1) <- df1[[1]]
df1 <- df1[-1] 
df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0
df1
#   x y z w r s
# a 1 2 0 0 0 0
# b 2 3 0 0 2 3
# c 3 4 1 2 3 4
# d 0 0 2 3 4 5
# e 0 0 3 4 0 0
# f 0 0 4 5 0 0
```

`tidyverse` can make things more compact/readable:

```
library(tidyverse)
lst %>%
  map(rownames_to_column) %>%
  reduce(full_join) %>%
  `[<-`(is.na(.),value=0) %>%
  column_to_rownames

#   x y z w r s
# a 1 2 0 0 0 0
# b 2 3 0 0 2 3
# c 3 4 1 2 3 4
# d 0 0 2 3 4 5
# e 0 0 3 4 0 0
# f 0 0 4 5 0 0
```

**merging directly by row names**

`merge` supports merging by row names if you set the argument `by` to `"row.names"` or to `0`, but strangely it returns a dataframe with a column `Row.names` and no actual row name. This makes the `Reduce` call much less smooth that it could have been, so in the end it's not much better, possibly worse, than my original base solution:

```
df1 <- Reduce(function(x,y) {
  z <- merge(x,y,all=T,by=0)
  rownames(z) <- z[[1]]
  z[-1]},
  lst)
df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0
```

Comment: Thanks! I prefer the way using tidyverse

Answer (score 3):

An alternative `tidyverse` solution that in my `microbenchmark` is very marginally faster than the other solution (~0.5 ms on a 5ms operation), but I think is a bit more hacky and certainly less neat. This approach basically avoids calling `full_join` so many times by simply row binding the data frames and then collapsing by rowname, trusting `mean, na.rm = TRUE` to just drop all except the one nonmissing value.

```r
library(tidyverse)
lst <- list(
  data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 2:4, row.names = letters[1:3]),
  data.frame(z = 1:4, w = 2:5, row.names = letters[3:6]),
  data.frame(r = 2:4, s = 3:5, row.names = letters[2:4])
)

lst %>%
  map(rownames_to_column) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  group_by(rowname) %>%
  summarise_all(mean, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  map_dfc(replace_na, 0)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#>   rowname     x     y     z     w     r     s
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a           1     2     0     0     0     0
#> 2 b           2     3     0     0     2     3
#> 3 c           3     4     1     2     3     4
#> 4 d           0     0     2     3     4     5
#> 5 e           0     0     3     4     0     0
#> 6 f           0     0     4     5     0     0
```

Created on 2018-06-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: That's neat, to be less hackish and probably improve performance yet again you could replace the `summarize_all` call with : `summarise_all(~invoke(coalesce,.x))` whose purposeis really to do what you want to do.

Comment: I was tempted to use `map_dfc` with `replace_na` as well but then you get a tibble and if you want to get back to the row names it's a mess again

Comment: Ah, I knew there ought to be a function for it but now I know the name! Yeah, I realised that having to convert to dataframe and replace the rownames would be kinda annoying - think your way is more convenient if you really want the rownames